# which of the following are true among the four statements?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

let {$f_n$} be sequence of integrable functions defined on an interval $[a,b]$. Then

a)  If $f_n(x)\to 0$ a.e., then $\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)dx \to 0$

b)  If $\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)dx \to 0$ then $f_n(x)\to 0$ a.e.

c) if $f_n(x)\to 0$ a.e.and each $f_n$ is bounded function, then $\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)dx \to 0$

d) if $f_n(x)\to 0$ a.e and $f_n$'s are uniformly bounded then $\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)dx \to 0$

I have no idea how to look for the solution of above?

Comment: What do you already know about these functions? Can you generalise them from a interval to a measure space?

Comment: Take the second one take $f_n(x)=x$ on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: $f_n(x) \to 0$ a.e. means where function not going to $0$ is set of measure $0$ in $[a,b]$

Comment: What does the 'uniformly' in c) mean?

Comment: sorry. let me correct it

Comment: @ YoTengoUnLCD  so b is false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statement (a) is false: let $[a,b]=[0,1]$, and define $f_n(x)=n\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$.

Statement (b) is false, even if the $f_n$ are required to be non-negative. Again let $[a,b]=[0,1]$, and define a sequence by $f_1=\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}$, $f_2=\chi_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}$, $f_3=\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{4}]}$, $f_4=\chi_{[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}]}$, and so on. This is sometimes called the "typewriter sequence" or the "floating, shrinking interval".

Statement (c) is false. The same example as for statement (a) works.

Statement (d) is true for Lebesgue measure on a compact interval $[a,b]$, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem.